# How can you update transition animation(fade in, fade out) from jframe to another jframe?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe, transition

I tried doing it but it seems like the transition is not fading in smoothly and some of the buttons after I clicked it is not opening or doing the animation transition of fade in/out. Here's my code:

```
        for (double i = 1.0; i >=0.0; i=i-0.1){
           String val=i+"";
        float f = Float.valueOf(val);
         this.setOpacity(f);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(30);
       }catch(Exception e){

       }
           StockItems a = new StockItems();
            a.setVisible(true);
            a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to get a better understanding of why you might be having problems and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for one possible solution

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)